# How to filter just one item from array with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple response :

```
[
   {
      "id":"1011",
      "name":"Popular Music"
   },
   {
      "id":"1012",
      "name":"Hip Hop & R&B"
   },
   {
      "id":"1014",
      "name":"House Music"
   },
   {
      "id":"1013",
      "name":"Bhangra & Bollywood"
   }
]
```

I want to get only the id of each item and assign it my v-model="music_style_ids". My input is:

```
<li>
    <input v-model="music_style_ids" type="checkbox" id="1017" value="1017">
    <label for="1017">Funk, Soul, Disco</label>
</li>
```

On my get method that i get this response i use:

```
if (response.data.music_style !== undefined) {
self.music_style_ids = response.data.music_style
}
```

I'm a newbie on Vuejs and i just don't know how to do it with Vuejs.
What i would like to get is: `["1011", "1012", "1014"]`

Is there a way to do it with JavaScript and simple assign it to my variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var t = [
   {
      "id":"1011",
      "name":"Popular Music"
   },
   {
      "id":"1012",
      "name":"Hip Hop & R&B"
   },
   {
      "id":"1014",
      "name":"House Music"
   },
   {
      "id":"1013",
      "name":"Bhangra & Bollywood"
   }
].map(function (a) { return a.id; });
console.log(t);
```

Hopes this is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Totally Dude, Thanks :)

Comment: Happy to help.
Please accept the answer if it solved your issue.